# Disable access to os and io library in Lua runtime

Tags: security, lua, sandbox

I'm designing simple sandbox to allow users run small lua scripts and being a bit paranoid I'm not satisfied by just putting it in restricted docker container. I wonder, if I set `os` and `io` to `nil` before running the script (i.e. adding these as two first lines) - will it completely prevent user from gaining access to those standard libraries? Are there any unwanted side-effects? (suppose users just need to solve some basic programming exercise, like finding n-th prime etc).

```lua
os = nil
io = nil
```

Comment: This might be interesting: https://github.com/kikito/lua-sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will it completely prevent user from gaining access to those standard libraries?

No. In particular, `load` is still available. This will allow loading [malicious bytecode](https://www.corsix.org/content/malicious-luajit-bytecode).

Likewise, the `debug` library is still available as an attack vector too. If the `debug` library is used, many assumptions about Lua don't hold anymore; it can be abused to gain access to otherwise inaccessible variables or to trigger undefined behavior in the interpreter (which may be or may not be exploitable).

> Are there any unwanted side-effects?

With your current `io.input`, `io.read`, `io.lines` and `io.write` will not be available for reading from stdin or writing to stdout (however `print` will still be available); how are your programs supposed to communicate with the host? Parameters and return values?

Harmless time & date functions like `os.clock`, `os.date`, `os.difftime` will also be inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! really typical `io` functions may be convenient and even time functions may be of interest to user sometimes. I'd better reduce my paranoia, there is not much to steal from empty VPS anyway even if user manages to ovecome docker container limitations. Also the hint in the comment above deserves deeper investigation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also it is worth a look on the Metatable Metamethods - Example: I destroy the ```userdata``` with: ```getmetatable(io.open('/dev/null')).__index = nil``` and than try to ```io.open()``` or ```io.popen()``` or and ```require()``` something New. - Yes - I know its not so nice but works :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you only set a "pointer" to nil this will still be possible...

```
package.loaded.os.execute('echo "That seems unwanted"')
```

or this

```
require("os").execute('echo "That too"')
```

In Lua all unwanted References (especially in `package.loaded`) should be set to `nil` and then it is ready for: `collectgarbage()`
Even if you think 'Than i set `package` to `nil`'

```
require("os").execute('echo "Oups - Didnt mentioned that"')
```

will work

Side Effects
It depends.
A well documented Sandbox should work fine.
A good Start is: Not actively developed
demo
On: [Luiz Henrique de Figueiredo: Libraries and tools for Lua](https://web.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/%7Elhf/ftp/lua/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanations! Quite useful for such a novice in Lua as I am!

Comment: Thats true - I wish i knew that i was a Novice - Another Exception: You know ```string``` Library? - Even if you do sandboxing ```string``` to ```nil``` in the right way every ```string``` has a Metamethod called ```__index``` (a table) with all ```string``` Library Functions as "last Reference" - You can get ```string``` Library back therefore with: ```string = getmetatable('Hello - I am a String').__index```